# Displaying a 3D model based on device rotation using web technologies

Tags: javascript, frameworks, augmented-reality

I'm looking for the best approach to achieve the following with today's web technologies:

A 3D model is rendered on screen and stays at a position. The position does not change and the model does not interact with the environment, therefore I'd call it "AR-light". If the user rotates his device, he will lose sight of the object, because it always stays at a position.

Later on, this position will be determined by a GPS signal, but that's something I don't focus right now.

Is there a good framework for this? AR.js seems to be too much for what I actually try to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using WebGL to display your model, then I believe three.js  gives you some routines that can vary the camera angle and position based on device movements.

[Threejs Rotating object with device orientation control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081699/threejs-rotating-object-with-device-orientation-control)

Alternatively, its usually best if you are learning something new, to try to access the device's accelerometer directly and try to convert movements into changes of camera position/orientation. see

[How to detect movement of an android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574879/how-to-detect-movement-of-an-android-device)